# metric from Christoffel symbols

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have 2 dimensional Riemannian manifold with Levi-Civita connection defined as follows:

$\Gamma^1_{jk}=0$  and  $\Gamma^2_{jk}(x^1,x^2)$ - any functions.
I try to characterize metrics that are compatible with these Christoffel symbols.
Therefore I used metric compatibility condition: $\nabla g=0$ and result with 8 PDEs:

$\frac{\partial g_{ab}}{\partial x^c}-\Gamma^d_{ac}g_{db}-\Gamma^d_{bc}g_{ad}=0$

However I am not able to solve them. Are they even solvable?
Should I use different method?

I will be gratefull for any sugestions.
Best regards.